# Rigid Body Bake Won't Delete

Tags: baking, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm doing a rigid body simulation, and I baked the simulation. But then I want to delete the bake, and change some things in the simulation, and then re-bake it. So I hit the "Delete Bake" Button, in the rigid body world settings.

But it still reads:
**599 Frames in Memory (4.7 MiB)**

And when I click on the Bake button again, it quickly bakes the frames that were already baked, and then keeps on baking. It sort of seems to "Skip over what it already baked". The problem, is that it uses the old bake, even though I told it to delete the bake. And this totally messes up the simulation. There is also the "Delete All Bakes" Button, but that doesn't do anything either. And even when I close and re-open the Blender file, it uses the old bake.

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: After deleting the bake make sure to move the playback timeline to frame 0 and hit calculate to frame.
this should clear all the previous cache!

Comment: are you using 2.93.3?  Because I've just started seeing the same problem with a very simple 3 body simulation and am starting to suspect a bug.

Comment: In 2.93.4, it doesn't delete the frames in memory, but if you change something and rebake the simulation the new bake does happen.  It looks like a bug.

Comment: @Nand27 Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @MartyFouts I am using Blender Version 2.93.0. I have not updated to the latest Blender version yet, because when I tried 2.93.3, the video editor had a lot of bugs, and was unusable for me. But it looks like version 2.93.4 is out now, so I will try using that.

I figured out, that If I change the simulation speed, and then re-bake it, it fixes the problem. So then I just cancel the bake, change the speed back to what I want, and re-bake it. Its slightly annoying, but it fixes the issue. But yeah, this might be a bug.

Comment: The good news is that .4 seems to be mostly VSE fixes. Hopefully they fixed the ones that bothered you.

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes, I just downloaded the lastest version, and the bugs appear to be fixed. Is there a website where the developers say what bugs were fixed? How did you know that .4 were mostly Video Editing fixes? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129240/discussion-between-marty-fouts-and-ryan-king-art).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @MartyFouts for helping figure out a solution.

If I change one of the simulation settings, and then re-bake, then it overrides the old bake and makes a new one. But it doesn't update the simulation if I just move the rigid body objects around in the scene. So I just have to change a setting, like the simulation speed, and then re-bake it. Then once it starts baking, I cancel the bake, change the simulation speed back to the speed that I want, and re-bake. That fixes the problem.